# Highlight and disable Listview items

Tags: java, android, android-listview, highlighting

I have a little Problem with my ListView.

I fill my ListView with an `ArrayList<String>` per `ArrayAdapter<String>` with more than 100 items.
Before my dialog will be show i want to highlight and disable some items. I have found the solution with `ListView.post(new Runnable() {...});`
I highlight my items with `lv.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`
and disbable an item with `lv.getChildAt(3).setEnabled(false);`
I do both also in an `OnItemClickListener()`.

Now my problem: 
if in the ListView are 11 items visible at runtime, the the highligt- and disable-pattern will repeat every 11 items. 
i.e. if i highlight just the 3. item also the 14., 25. ... item will get a blue background.
And if i disable the 4. item also the 15. and 26. and so on is disabled.

If i scroll fast to buttom and back to top other items are highlighted and disabled.

Another problem is, that i can only access the first (11) visible items in the post-runnable. If i try to highlight the 20. item the app will crash with a NullPointerException.

What can i do to prevent the "item-recycling" and to get full access to all items before the Dialog is shown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand what you want to achieve but here are some suggestions for you.

1) Always Recycle, you should never avoid recicling since you maybe run into another problem, you will run out of memory.

2) In your model implement the checkeable interface, so the model should know if an item is selected or not, **Not the view only**

3) When iterating each element make use of a ViewHolder and then check the model to see if the elment being inflaed it selected or not and use the desired color

Please have a look at this example [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/), it describes the use of CAB (Contextual Action Bar) but it uses the things i'm mentioning.

I hope it helps you.